# Как правильно поставить ударение?

Tags: фонетика

Слышу в речи оба варианта: парАлич и паралИч. А как же правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

паралИч, разумеется.
Даже не знаю, где вы могли слышать иное. 
Хотя в словаре Зарвы есть упоминание о таком варианте (как неправильном), но сталкиваться не приходилось.